Memory alignment to a power of 2
While reading through some code, I stumbled upon these lines:
char **vectorize_this_str (const char *src) {
#define pSZ  (sizeof(char*))
    // [...]
    tot = strlen(src) + 1;                       
    // [...]
    adj = (pSZ-1) - ((tot + pSZ-1) & (pSZ-1));   // calc alignment bytes
    cpy = calloc(1, tot + adj + (2 * pSZ));      // get new larger buffer
    // [...]
}

As part of the function vectorize_this_str, the alignment to a multiple of sizeof(char*) is computed. Can someone explain how this formula works?

@RetiredNinja: That is about finding the next power of two greater than or equal to x, not finding the next multiple of p greater than or equal to x.

First, it must be noted that this formula only works when the alignment is to a power of 2.
The best way to understand the formula is to derive it ourselves. Let's start with an example.
On most 64-bit systems, sizeof(char*) = 8. Let's assume our input string src is "What a nice day to go out", totalling 25 characters, so that tot = 26 (including the null byte). Since we're aligning to a power of 2, it's best to represent everything in binary. Therefore, 8(10) = 1000(2) and 26(10) = 101010(2).
Before we proceed, let's define alignment. An address x is aligned to a boundary a if x is a multiple of a. For binary numbers aligned to powers of 2, this takes a much nicer form: x is aligned to a power of 2n if the first n bits of the number are 0. Therefore, 101000 is aligned to an 8 = 23 byte boundary, while 101010 is not.
Therefore, we see that to align a number x to a 2n boundary we only need to look at the last n bits and find a number y which added to x turns all those bits to 0.
My first approach was to extract the last n bits of x, negate them, add them to x, and add a 1. For example:
101[010] +
     ^------- last 3 bits
000[101]
________
101[111] + // now just add a 1 to flip all 3 bits to 0
000[001]
________
110[000]

Ta-da! To implement this, we first negate x, ~x. To extract the last n bits, we use a bitwise & with 2n-1, since that gives us a mask of n-1 1's: ~x & (a - 1), where the alignment a is 2n. Now adding 1, we get that the padding required for x to be aligned to a is: p = ~x & (a - 1) + 1.
This is almost correct, but there's an edge case. Note what happens when x is already divisible by a; Let's take x = 101000 and a = 1000:
101[000] +
000[111]
________
101[111] +
000[001]
________
110[000]

While the final result is aligned to an 8-byte boundary, we skipped 8 bytes for no reason! That's inefficient, but luckily we can do better.

To move forward, note that the largest number we need to add to x in order to align it to a 2n boundary is 2n-1. So let's just do that: aligned_x = x + (a - 1) - overshoot. If we can find a formula for the overshoot, we can solve our previous issue.
For our example:
101[010]+
000[111]
________
110[001] // the overshoot is the number in square brackets

To extract the overshoot, we know we can a bitwise and on the last result: overshoot = (x + (a - 1)) & (a - 1).
Putting it all together, we get that x_aligned = x + [(a - 1) - (x + (a - 1)) & (a - 1)], or
pad = (a - 1) - ((x + (a - 1)) & (a - 1))

which is exactly the formula used in the quoted code!

Why not tot = - (-tot & -pSZ);?

@EricPostpischil: Is tot reassigned the aligned value? I've tried this formula with tot = 101010 and pSZ = 001000, but I don't seem to get the expected result (110000).

Given tot = 101010 and pSZ = 001000, then -tot = 111…111010110, and -pSZ = 111…111111000, so -tot & -pSZ = 111…111010000, and the negation of that is 000…000110000.

@EricPostpischil I thought your - is the bitwise negation, but I see -x = ~x + 1. This is great! Would you like to write an answer explaining the thought process for arriving at this formula? A proof of mathematical equivalence between the two would be a bonus.
